# How to find all packages and its version used in my project?

Tags: python

I have a python project and I want to write a 'requirements' for it.So I need to find all packages used in my project.
Is there an easy way to do it ?

Comment: `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. This lists all the installed packages along with the specific version.

Comment: turned comment into community wiki answer, see below.

Comment: pipreqs works fine.

Answer (score 8):

### pipreqs

pip freeze list all packages installed, use pipreqs. Pipreqs generate requirements.txt file for any project based on imports.

```
pip install pipreqs


Usage:
    pipreqs [options] <path>

Options:
    --use-local           Use ONLY local package info instead of querying PyPI
    --pypi-server <url>   Use custom PyPi server
    --proxy <url>         Use Proxy, parameter will be passed to requests library. You can also just set the
                          environments parameter in your terminal:
                          $ export HTTP_PROXY="http://10.10.1.10:3128"
                          $ export HTTPS_PROXY="https://10.10.1.10:1080"
    --debug               Print debug information
    --ignore <dirs>...    Ignore extra directories
    --encoding <charset>  Use encoding parameter for file open
    --savepath <file>     Save the list of requirements in the given file
    --print               Output the list of requirements in the standard output
    --force               Overwrite existing requirements.txt
```

[Project on github](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs)

Comment: this is probably the better solution compared to `pip freeze` in this case.

Comment: Yes, I also think it's a better way to achieve that. You can even ignore unit tests with the *--ignore* flag.

Comment: When using  pipreqs --use-local path/to/dir the only output I get is Usage:
    pipreqs [options] <path>

Answer (score 0):

You could do so by running `pip freeze > requirements.txt`.
I suggest go through this [link](https://www.fullstackpython.com/application-dependencies.html) here, as it's well explained.

The `pip freeze` command does the following, as per the [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/):

```
Output installed packages in requirements format.
```

so when running `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, you are writing the installed packages on a `.txt` file.

Comment: what if user is not using virtualenv?  I have PySide project, but when I do pip freeze, pyside is not listed anywhere

Comment: Please don't just copy an answer from the comments. Or then make it a community wiki answer. (Like the one below.)

Comment: In fact, this can be considered a quick and dirty way to extract the project requirements because you make a naive snapshot of what you have in your virtualenv: your virtualenv may contains some libraries only useful for development (which should be excluded). What you really need is the libraries required to run your application (and only that). You may add extra requirements for : unit testing (nose, pytest…), style checking (pylint…), documentation (sphinx…). And so on…

Comment: I am new here and doing my best to learn and contribute. Not trying to copy or anything like this. Your question regarding the virtual environment, I am trying to understand and answer to myself as well.

Answer (score -2):

*original answer from my comment:*

You can use [pip freeze](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/) for listing **all installed packages** with the specific version:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

This will work well, especially if you are using [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/). If not, and you only want to list packages requested in a specific project, consider @Sidon's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43719052/1622937).

Comment: what if user is not using virtualenv? I have PySide project, but when I do pip freeze, pyside is not listed anywhere

Comment: you don't need to user virtualenv to use `pip freeze`. If you installed pyside for the same python interpreter as your pip is using, it will show up in the requirements. Alternatively, `pip show pyside` will tell you whether you have pyside installed or not.